# Poisson process continuous discharge

Tags: markov-chains, poisson-process

I am currently working on an exercise on Poisson processes and I'm completely stuck. The question is as follows:

Suppose that you earn random iid amounts of money $X_i$ at times $T_i$, which occur according to a Poisson process $N(\cdot)$. It turns out that the richer you are the faster you spend money. Assume continuously at some rate $rx$ with $r>0$, for an account balance x. The bank account balance then follows the equation:

$$ B(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{N(t)} X_i \ e^{-r(t-T_i)} $$

Calculate the expected account balance at time $t$, i.e. $\mathbb{E}B(t)$

The hint is given to condition on $N(t)$ and $T_1,T_2,...,T_{N(t)}$.

I am absolutely clueless how to start. I figured that when I condition on $N(t) = n$ the jump times have joint density function $f(T_1,...,T_n) = n! \ t^{-n} \  \mathbb{1}_{(0 \leq T_1 \leq ... \leq T_n \leq t)}$